# Configuration of Nexus private repository

Tags: nexus

I'm starting to work to a new project and I'm evaluating the use of Nexus to manage the artifacts. What I need is a private repository that allow me to store on a private server my artifacts and at the same time to store, let's say on the same server, the artifact that are dependencies for my project.

I saw that there are 3 different type of repository available in nexus, and two of them (Hoisted and Proxy) has properties that I need, as I can evaluate from [this](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Managing+Repositories) documentation.

Can someone give me more detailed informations about the correct configuration of my repository to achieve the goals I described before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What artifact types do you have?  Are the dependancies home grown or from the internet (open source resources)?

Comment: There are both home grown dependencies and open source internet resources; artifacts are wars or ears

Comment: FYI wars and ears sound like the maven format, however, I offered a general answer below to help others who might come later, or if your needs grow.  One advantage of NXRM is that it can span multiple formats so can be good if your workplace uses multiple format types (now or later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have home grown artifacts as well as pull open source dependancies from the internet, a common configuration suggested is a "hosted" repository for your own stuff, a "hosted" repository for 3rd party stuff (not written by you but not internet accessible) and at least one proxy repository to where you get your internet artifacts from, then put them all in a repository group for one URL to access all of them from.

This is shown for example [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/.NET+Package+Repositories+with+NuGet#id-.NETPackageRepositorieswithNuGet-NuGetGroupRepositories).

What Format type will depend on what your artifacts are.  If Java then Maven, if nupkgs then NuGet etc.  If you explore the Sonatype documentation more, you'll note that Nexus Repository 3 has support for types that Nexus Repository 2 doesn't.  This is noteworthy because you just linked the Nexus Repository 2 docs, but it might not even be the right choice for you.

You can't mix and match groups with formats, so if you use (for example) both Maven and NuGet you'd need two groups.

Not all formats are supported by NXRM either, so if you have ones we don't support, you can look for a ticket suggesting implementation and watch and guide any acceptance in the Sonatype NEXUS project of JIRA (https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/NEXUS/).

The Sonatype [user group](https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/nexus-users) or [community website](https://community.sonatype.com) are likely better places for general questions of this nature and also good for specific questions about problems you are having before filing a bug ticket in the JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration I used is those described in [this](http://codeheaven.io/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts/) link: it's similar to those described by joedragons in the answer above.

While I'm working in java, I used three pre-defined repository provided with the nexus installation: the one pointing to maven central and two others for my snapshots and releases. I grouped them under a group.

Quite simple, but I think it will be sufficient to cover my needs.